# Tag exclusion when searching questions?

Tags: support, tags, search, tag-search

Currentlly I'm using this query to search for programming questions in one of the StackExchange sites:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net+or+vb.net+or+vbscript+or+batch-file+or+cmd

Is there a way to exclude a tag in the query?.

I mean that for example in this query I want to perform a search of [C#] tag but I want to exclude questions that are tagged with [.net] tag:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23

I don't want to get questions that are tagged with both [C#] and [.net], only [C#].

Is possible?. If not, then please consider this as a feature request.

Answer (score 5):

Put a `-` in front of the tags you wish to exclude.

In your case the whole search would be:

```
[c#] -[.net]
```

You can see this at the bottom of the "advanced search tips" on the [search page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search), as well as the [How do I search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) help center article.

> To exclude results from a tag, term or phrase, prefix it with - in your query: waffles -unicorns finds posts that mention tasty batter-based breakfasts without including mythical creatures, while [laurel] -[hardy] includes only posts pertaining to the first half of the classic comedy couple.

Comment: Thanks for answer, could you please explain how I combine the exclusion with the OR operators? this dont works: `[.net] or [vb.net] -[wpf] -[asp.net]` I still get wpf and asp.net questions.

Comment: `[.net] or [vb.net] and -[wpf] and -[asp.net]` seems to work.

Comment: Thanks but didn't worked, I get a regular search results instead of a 'Tagged Questions' search results.

Comment: That's the extent of the system at the moment. It does search via tags, however. Take a look at the side bar - it matches exactly this search.